# Excel Error Bars From Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-table

When Excel generates Standard Error error bars, it takes into account the number of data points. If a chart was generated from a pivot table, does Excel use the number of points in the pivot table, 1, or the number of values in the chart that the pivot table was based on?

**EDIT**
To clarify, let's say I have a long list of many columns. I then create a pivot table that has the average of each column. Then, I create a chart of those averages and add error bars to that chart. Will the error bars be based on the standard deviation of the original long columns, or on the standard deviation of the averages in the pivot chart?

Comment: Data points in a chart/graph are generated from the data selected. You're question is rather vague. Can you explain what are you trying to do and where are you getting stuck so someone can give you a specific answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. Added clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can find out by a simple experiment.

I just created a table with two sets of data and put a graph beneath it with error bars. Then a Pivot table and a chart based on the pivot table and put some error bars in there too. As you can(n't) see, the chart of the pivoted data  calculates an standard deviation of 0. My conclusion is that the error bars are calculated on the selected data (just as @CharlieRB pointed out) and not on the source of the selected data.

[image: Some tables and some charts with error bars]